# Deploy SharePoint 2013 app to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app

I was wondering if an "app" programmed for SharePoint 2013 is backwards compatible with SharePoint 2010?

My company has "apps" built for 2013 (Office 365) using JavaScript; however, I am not finding information if I can take the same "app" and put it on a SharePoint 2010 hosted system without any additional changes to code or re-coding the whole project. Does SharePoint 2010 have an "app" catalog?

Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I'm afraid not, the whole concept of apps is new in SharePoint 2013.

In 2010 you are limited to farm or sandboxed solutions, with Webparts and lists being the main building blocks most similar to at least SP Hosted Apps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Robert. I guess we have no other option to re-code the "app" into a "solution".

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @robert,

You can not deploy the SP2013 app as is onto SharePOint 2010,  however if your app contains just couple of Javascript files and lists,  you can try to mimic it using manual approach and associate JS code to the page using Content Editor web part.

SharePoint 2013 apps essentially just contains reference to jQuery and provides you the deployment mechanism from Visual Studio 2013.